# input function for inference with pre-made Estimator in version 1.14

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have this input function which works OK

```
def classify_input_fn(image_filename, command):
    file_contents = tf.io.read_file(image_filename)
    image_decoded = preprocess_image(file_contents)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((image_decoded, command))
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    image, command = iterator.get_next()
    return {"image":image, "command":command}
```

`command` is an integer.

but tf 1.14 gives a warning of

`W0722 11:37:39.224976 10956 deprecation.py:323]` ... `DatasetV1.make_one_shot_iterator (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated` ...

The warning suggests returning the dataset directly but that fails because it doesn't have a dictionary of feature columns. What's the correct way to make a simple input function to do inference on a single example?

I tried simply returning a dict like

```
def classify_input_fn(image_filename, command):
    file_contents = tf.io.read_file(image_filename)
    image_decoded = preprocess_image(file_contents)
    return {"image":image_decoded, "command":command}
```

but that fails with

```
ValueError: Feature (key: command) cannot have rank 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the dataset contain dictionaries of tensors instead of tuples of tensors. Then you can directly return the dataset from the input function instead of using the deprecated `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`.

```
def predict_input_fn(image_filename, command):
    file_contents = tf.io.read_file(image_filename)
    image_decoded = preprocess_image(file_contents)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors({"image":image_decoded, "command":command})
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)
    return dataset
```